# Are IVs reset when Unlocking Potential?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I have a 4-star Robin with high defense and low resistance. If I unlock his potential to upgrade him to a 5-star, will he still have high defense and low resistance, or will his IVs be re-randomized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the FAQ on [this](https://fireemblem.gamepress.gg/fire-emblem-heroes-iv-calculator) IV Calculator, your IVs remain the same when unlocking potential.